# How to test window.addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Here is an event listener added, if I want to test if this event listener is working or not, how do I test? window.postMessage doesn't seem to be triggering this event. Basically, how do I trigger "some_event" so that my EventListener runs?

```
window.addEventListener('some_event', function() {
    console.log("some_event triggered");
});
```

Please note, I was able to reproduce with "click" event, but what I want to know is, how do I know if any string is passed as an event. Example:

```
window.addEventListener('add_to_cart', function() {
    console.log("some_event triggered");
});
```

So I would like to simulate this event listener to check if it's working or not. How do I test this?

Comment: Do you mean to write a test that clicks the dom for you and then proves if the window.addEventListener(...){} got called? If yes.why do you want to check if native functionalities work?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use some concrete event name like for example `click` - and click on browser page window - eg:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("some_event triggered");
});
```

Here is some [info about events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and situations when they are trigger.

### After question update

Yes you can define and fire arbitrary events - read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). And here is some example code:

```js
var event = new Event('some_event');

// Listen for the event.
window.addEventListener('some_event', function (e) { 
    console.log('some_event triggered') 
}, false);

// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

So you fire event using `window.dispatchEvent(event)` and this is the way you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event using `dispatchEvent` and `fireEvent` in IE.

```
 var ev, element = window;
  if (document.createEvent) {
    ev = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    ev.initEvent("eventname", true, true);
    ev.eventName = "eventname";
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);
  } else {
    ev = document.createEventObject();
    ev.eventType = "eventname";
    ev.eventName = "eventname";
    element.fireEvent("on" + ev.eventType, event);
  }
```

```js
function triggerEvent(elem, name){
   var ev;
  if (document.createEvent) {
    ev = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    ev.initEvent(name, true, true);
    ev.eventName = name;
    elem.dispatchEvent(ev);
  } else {
    ev = document.createEventObject();
    ev.eventType = name;
    ev.eventName = name;
    elem.fireEvent("on" + ev.eventType, event);
  }
}
window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log("Clicked");
});
window.addEventListener("custom_event", function(e){
   console.log("custom_event triggered");
});
triggerEvent(window, "click");
triggerEvent(window, "custom_event");
```